# Paypal won't load using casperjs

Tags: javascript, paypal, casperjs

I'm trying to acces paypal web using casperjs (and loging in), I want to take a screenshot of the page, to see if it's working, but the screenshots is empty and I'm getting a warning:

`[warning] [phantom] Loading resource failed with status=fail: https://www.paypal.com/`

This is my code:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: 'debug',
    viewportSize: {
        width: 1920,
        height: 1440
    }
});

var options = casper.cli.options;

if(options['url'] == null) {
    casper.echo('No URL found');
    casper.exit();
}

if(options['userAgent'] == null ){
    casper.userAgent(
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36'
    );
} else {
    casper.userAgent(options['userAgent']);
}

casper.start(options['url'], function(){
    this.capture("screenshots/casper_start.png");
});

casper.waitForSelector('#btnLogin', function(){
    this.fill('form name=["login"]',{
        '#email': 'xxxxxx',
        '#password': 'xxxxxx'
    },true)
}, function(){
    this.capture("screenshots/id_choose_timeout.png");
});

casper.wait(2000,function(){
   this.capture("screenshots/wait2000.png");
});

casper.run();
```

This is the command I'm running:

`casperjs --ssl-protocol=any paypal.js --url=https://www.paypal.com/signin`

I also tried the SAME code but with google, and works fine.

Comment: Maybe add `--ignore-ssl-errors=true`?

Comment: Which PhantomJS version do you use? Please register to the `resource.error`, `page.error`, `remote.message` and `casper.page.onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-2_caspererrors-js)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: @ArtjomB. also tried that, same result. I'm using version 2.0.0

Comment: Can you open paypal from that IP in normal browser?

Comment: @Vaviloff Yes, paypal works perfectly on a normal browser

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue with CasperJS from Master and PhantomJS 2.0.0 on Windows. Are you sure that your CasperJS installation uses the correct PhantomJS executable? If you installed CasperJS through npm, it will try to use its own PhantomJS version.

Comment: @ArtjomB. But if isn't the correct executable... why it works with google's url and not with paypal's one?

Comment: Because google and paypal are entirely different sites. Anything can happen.

Comment: I tried using phantomjs directly instead casperjs, and it loads the page